# How can I do a full text search in my databse

Tags: c#, t-sql, asp.net-core-mvc

My c# app calls for sql stored function called Search, and passes some search term. I am using EasyFTS library whcich is available here : https://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/data/easy-full-text-search-queries

So the app passes a search term, stored function processes it, and returns search result.

My table-valued function looks like this :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Search] 

(

    @locale NVARCHAR(10),
    @searchTerm NVARCHAR(450)
)
RETURNS 
@retSearch TABLE 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,

    [Table] NVARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
    [Title] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Summary] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Rank] INT NOT NULL,
    [Parameters] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([Id],[Table])
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    IF @locale = N''
    BEGIN
        SET @locale = N'en'
    END
    INSERT @retSearch 
    SELECT Id,[Table],[Title],[Summary], RANK  [Rank],[Parameters]
    FROM dbo.FTSData  EP
    INNER JOIN
    CONTAINSTABLE(dbo.FTSData,Content,
            @searchTerm) AS KEY_TBL
              ON EP.IdFtsData = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
              WHERE EP.LocaleId=@locale
              ORDER BY RANK DESC

   RETURN

END
```

The problem is that the search result cannot search partial words.
Example : FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, **powershe**), won't find content that has the word **powershell** in it.

I tried to use LIKE and adding a new variable in function and concatenate % on both side of search value
**SET @searchTermFun = '%'+@searchTerm+'%'** and that works on database side(SSMS).
But when I try to implement it in my function It doesn't work. Is the problem in **CONTAINSTABLE** ?

Test example:

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm AS NVARCHAR(50), @locale AS NVARCHAR(10), @searchTermFun AS NVARCHAR(450)
SET @SearchTerm = 'course'
SET @SearchTermFun = '%'+@SearchTerm+'%'
SET @locale = 'en'
SELECT Id,[Table],[Title],[Summary],[Parameters], LocaleId
FROM dbo.FTSData  EP
WHERE  EP.LocaleId=@locale AND Content LIKE @SearchTermFun
ORDER by [Table] DESC
```

Comment: Full text search is not designed for partial words, not sure why you thought it was. Also it will probably perform better if you use an inline TV function `RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN(SELECT ...)` rather than a multi-statement one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, I added an asterisk(*) on the end of the search string using the StringBuilder class in my .NET Core app. It solved my problem.

It is explained on this page:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/17653360-2c72-4647-96f0-d3a2a9e67f0e/searching-partial-and-or-full-word-from-fulltext-search-those-might-be-precise-or-fuzzy-less?forum=transactsql

Thanks anyway [@Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface)